# Ansible Playbook - Task is stuck on execution

Tags: apache, ansible

I'm currently learning Ansible by trying to automating stuff like installing and configuring a webserver. My problem is that the Task for running the command "**a2dismod deflate**" using Ansible Apache2 module is stuck on execution.

Here's the full playbook:

```
- name: Install apache2
  apt: name=apache2 update_cache=yes state=latest

- name: Ensure apache2 is running
  service:
          name: apache2
          state: started
          enabled: true
  
- name: Enable modules needed for redirection and SSL
  apache2_module:
          state: present
          name: "{{ item }}"
  with_items:
     - rewrite
     - headers
     - proxy
     - proxy_http
     - ssl
     - cache
 
- name: Disable module
  apache2_module:
          state: absent
          name: "{{ item }}"
  with_items:
     - deflate
 
- name: Configure apache2 - AllowOverride None to AllowOverride All
 
  lineinfile:
          path: /etc/apache2/apache2.conf
          regexp: '^(\s*)AllowOverride\s+None(\s*)$'
          line: '\1AllowOverride All\2'
          backrefs: yes
          state: present
          insertafter: '^<Directory /var/www>'
          insertbefore: '^</Directory>'
  
- name: Restart apache2
  service:
          name: apache2
          state: restarted
```

I tried checking out the process on the target server and it seems like the command was successfully executed, however it was stuck after running this specific command: "**/usr/bin/htcacheclean -d 120 -p /var/cache/apache2/mod_cache_disk -l 300M -n**"

```
root       41728  0.0  0.0   2888   988 pts/1    Ss+  10:21   0:00      \_ /bin/sh -c /usr/bin/python3 /root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1676974885.4424312-24196163579435/AnsiballZ_
root       41729  0.0  2.4  35024 24104 pts/1    S+   10:21   0:00          \_ /usr/bin/python3 /root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1676974885.4424312-24196163579435/AnsiballZ_apache2
root       41733  0.0  0.8  14252  8796 pts/1    S+   10:21   0:00              \_ /usr/bin/perl -w /usr/sbin/a2dismod deflate
root        1253  0.0  0.8 295540  8756 ?        Ssl  09:24   0:00 /usr/libexec/packagekitd
root       13942  0.0  0.5  11532  5644 ?        Ss   09:27   0:00 /lib/systemd/systemd-udevd
systemd+   14243  0.0  0.5  16120  5712 ?        Ss   09:27   0:00 /lib/systemd/systemd-networkd
systemd+   14249  0.0  0.8  25260  8884 ?        Ss   09:27   0:00 /lib/systemd/systemd-resolved
root       14251  0.0  1.1  31320 11036 ?        S<s  09:27   0:00 /lib/systemd/systemd-journald
systemd+   14322  0.0  0.4  89356  4956 ?        Ssl  09:27   0:00 /lib/systemd/systemd-timesyncd
root       25995  0.1  2.4 735960 24048 ?        Ssl  09:28   0:04 /usr/lib/snapd/snapd
root       39584  0.0  0.4   6768  4480 ?        Ss   09:29   0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data   39586  0.0  0.4 752984  4380 ?        Sl   09:29   0:00  \_ /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data   39587  0.0  0.4 752984  4380 ?        Sl   09:29   0:00  \_ /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data   39707  0.0  0.0   3736   160 ?        Ss   09:29   0:00 /usr/bin/htcacheclean -d 120 -p /var/cache/apache2/mod_cache_disk -l 300M -n
root       40930  0.0  0.9  17088  9360 ?        Ss   10:19   0:00 /lib/systemd/systemd --user
root       40931  0.0  0.4 170712  4360 ?        S    10:19   0:00  \_ (sd-pam)
```

Comment: "stuck on execution", no logs nothing?  Ansible times out eventually?  Have you tried it manually to see if the command itself works (i.e. it is not an Ansible problem per say).

Comment: Yes no logs, nothing. The task is just stuck after running the command. I already tried running the command as well and it works fine

Comment: Have you already tried [`force: true`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/7/collections/community/general/apache2_module_module.html#parameter-force) which has the description "and override Debian warnings."? There are a bunch of other force-ish looking options, too; I'd guess `a2dismod` is waiting for you to confirm the removal

Comment: Hi @mdaniel, you were right I forgot to update this thread. The solution is to add "force: true", the reason why the playbook is stuck is because there's a warning prompt if you execute the a2dismod command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to add "force: true", the reason why the playbook is stuck is because there's a warning prompt if you execute the a2dismod command.